# How to make text a different color on overlap in HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to make some animations with text and for the colours I'd like for the text colour to change depending on the background (the objects it overlaps). However, the effect I'm after doesn't work simply with opacity as I would like a different colour altogether.

For instance:
[image]

Note that I made this example using GIMP. Also note that the text wouldn't be always aligned/overlapping like this but only during an animation.

Is this effect relatively easy to do or would it require complex JavaScript code and libraries?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us the HTML/relevant CSS of your example - save us having to make it up ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example There may be combinations of mix-blend-mode that help get the overlaps changing colors for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of the sort of thing that can be done using mix-blend-mode.

This snippet just uses difference - you will have to try out different methods depending on the color combinations you want.

Using difference on the two bits of text and putting them on a white background and making the texts yellow to start with converts them to a sort of blue and then when the animated text hits the blueish background we get a lighter shade.

I'm afraid I've never found a simple, algorithmic way of deciding what values should be given to mix-blend-mode and always end up with experimenting.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #5920d6 0 40%, transparent 40% 100%);
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container>* {
  color: #5920d6;
  color: yellow;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.static {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: yellow;
}

.move {
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 10s linear infinite;
  top: calc(40% + 0.25em);
  color: yellow;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, -0.1em);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(50vw, -0.1em);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="static">Some text</div>
  <div class="move">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the text a different color on overlap, you can set the mix-blend-mode property to difference or exclusion. These values will create a color effect that will invert or cancel out the color of the background on the overlapping area.

Here's an example of how to use the mix-blend-mode property to make text a different color on overlap:

```css
/* Apply the mix-blend-mode property to the overlapping element */
.overlapping-element {
  mix-blend-mode: difference; /* or exclusion */
}

/* Style the text to be overlapped */
.overlapping-text {
  color: white; /* the default color of the text */
}
```

The mix-blend-mode property is set to difference or exclusion to create a color effect. The overlapping-text is styled with the default color of the text, which will be inverted or cancelled out on the overlapping area.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about CSS animation on w3school web :

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp